# new iphone - how to delete app off of Developer Device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

really simple question. tried googling

I just got a new iPhone 4S and restored from backup. A development app doesn't show up but now that am deploying app to device, the old one shows up (for example, an old display.png is shown). Is there a way to fully delete this from the iPhone? Similar to just `rm -rf` in the simulator? If I go into the Organizer, I can see that I can 'delete' the application but it clearly lives on with the wrong default.png (and probably wrong sqlite db). How can I fully remove this?

thx

Comment: Holding your finger down on the app icon in the phone and then clicking on the "X" that appears on the shaking icon doesn't do it? Also, look in iTunes and under the list of "Applications" that are associated with your iPhone and delete the old app there, too.

Comment: thx .... so I did that but it is still showing the old display.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deleting the app from the device only, then you just delete it like any other app, either as you already know through the organizer, or by long pressing and clicking the 'x' on the icon.

If you have an issue with resources persisting after they have been replaced and you are building directly to the device, you may need to remove transient directories from your disk.

Transient directories for building are located in your home directory:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Remove the transient directory for your application and this will guarantee that all old resources are removed from the new build.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have tried all the way and other answer describe you how to delete the app from device, `*and still if you are getting the same issue*`, **then** i would suggest you to use following alternate way :

**1 ) Connect your device to your iTunes**

**2 ) Click on Apps in your LIBRARY section**

**3 ) Delete your app by right click**

It will surely help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Press-and-hold on the app icon on the device, then click the X button and select delete.

Then in XCode, navigate to the Product menu and select Clean.

Rebuild the app onto your device, and everything should work just fine (provided you perform the steps in this order). :)

Hope this helps!